# enabling authentication in ignite

Tags: java, server, ignite

I am running this code, i want to enable the authentication in apache ignite 2.7.6. It still shows `authentication = off`

How do i enable the authentication?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClientException, Exception {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ignite_sample","root","99@Jj");
    // Apache Ignite node configuration.
    IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();

    // Ignite persistence configuration.
    DataStorageConfiguration storageCfg = new DataStorageConfiguration();

    // Enabling the persistence.
    storageCfg.getDefaultDataRegionConfiguration().setPersistenceEnabled(true);

    // Applying settings.
    cfg.setDataStorageConfiguration(storageCfg);

    // Enable authentication
    cfg.setAuthenticationEnabled(true);

    Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(cfg);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess it's because you try to create the connection before the server node was started.

Try next:

1)Start server with authenticationEnabled=true and persistenceEnabled=true (for default region)

2)Then run next:

```
// Register JDBC driver.
Class.forName("org.apache.ignite.IgniteJdbcThinDriver");

// Open the JDBC connection.
try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ignite:thin://127.0.0.1:10800?" +
    "user=client&password=password"))
{
    conn.createStatement().executeQuery("select 1");
    System.out.println("Done");
}
catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

UPDATE:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <!-- Ignite configuration. -->
    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
        <property name="authenticationEnabled" value="true"/>

        <property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
                <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
                        <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true"/>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>

        <!-- TCP discovery SPI -->
        <property name="discoverySpi">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
                <property name="ipFinder">
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
                        <property name="addresses">
                            <list>
                                <value>127.0.0.1:47500</value>
                            </list>
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: can you share the sample code that contains those two(authenticationEnabled=true and persistenceEnabled=true (for default region)) statements? i want to enable by java code itself, not by xml.

Comment: i got the following error:  Spring XML configuration path is invalid: examples\config\igniteconf.xml. Note that this path should be either absolute or a relative local file system path, relative to META-INF in classpath or valid URL to IGNITE_HOME.

Comment: Have you tried specifying absolute path to that file?

Comment: i fixed that problem.. now i am able to run the above xml. The persistence is enabled but the authentication is still shows off..

Comment: I guess it's ok if you don't see it in the logs. Apache Ignite advanced security works only for thin clients (like ODBC/JDBC/etc). So it will not work for thick nodes and I guess it will not be printed in the log. Were you able to connect using JDBC without a password and username after enabling this feature?

Comment: No,  if u don't mind, can you please send me the sample xml and java client code for enabling the authentication in apache ignite?